# GWT - What's the shortest way of simply sharing strings and number constants between Java code and UiBinder files?

Tags: gwt, constants, sharing, uibinder

Can someone post an example of the shortest way of sharing a (preferably static final) string or number constant between Java code and UiBinder XML, where I can use the constant either in an attribute:

`<g:TextArea width="...px"/>`

or in a value:

`<g:Label>...</g:Label>`

I can't seem to find an example of this, only text from a file, which I don't want.

Comment: Ui binder mechanism is not designed to work like that. You define there a markup and in the widget code you can set additional attributes to your dynamic components.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`static` fields (and enum constants) can be used with a simple `<ui:import>`:

```
<ui:import field="com.example.Pojo.CONSTANT" />
```

or

```
<ui:import field="com.example.Pojo.*" />
```

and then simply:

```
<g:Label text="{CONSTANT}" />
```

or

```
<g:Label><ui:text from="{CONSTANT}"/></g:Label>
```

See https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/uibinder/test/client/WidgetBasedUi.ui.xml#87 for an example.

Comment: Thanks! It currently only works with `<ui:import...`. Is there a plan to merge that with `ui:with`?

Comment: Thomas, is it efficient even if I have a big class which contains the constants? Does it only import the static final constants and nothing else (hopefully)? Is it limited only to primitives and Strings?

Comment: Re. `ui:import`, ah, oops, my bad! I'll update the answer. Otherwise, the generator actually creates a field in the generated class, one per static field in the imported class, initialized with the fully-qualified name of the constant; so it shouldn't really matter whether you use the wildcard or import each needed field.

Comment: Thomas, if I use `*`, does it import non-final static fields too, and does it ignore any non-String, non-primitive static members of that class?

Comment: A quick look at the code tells me it doesn't check whether the field is `final` or not, and the field's type doesn't matter. Try it for yourself, and look at the generated code (hint: pass `-gen someFolder` to the Compiler or DevMode)